# Programmatically prevent browser-based code from making HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, websecurity

How to prevent 3rd-party JS code from making an HTTP request from my web app?

A Node-based web app with an SPA framework (e.g React) imports hundreds, if not thousands, of 3rd-party packages. I have no hope of reviewing all that source for security vulnerabilities and zero-day exploits mean patches can come too late. I'm particularly worried about HTTP requests being made by code that would collect and send user data to outside services.

I would like to prevent any code in 3rd-party libraries making HTTP requests, whether it be through calls to `fetch()`, `XMLHttpRequest`, form-posting, or any other means.

I can imagine wrapping `fetch` and other functions with my own versions of these that effectively make it so that only my app's code can use them.

Still, I worry there will be attack vectors I'll miss, especially around DOM manipulation where elements could be inserted like image tags that cause an HTTP request that sends a payload in the querystring.

I'm interested in build-time (static code analysis), as well as run-time solutions. And if there is existing software that handles the task, so much the better.

Comment: You could use a serviceworker like for a PWA, but do not use cacheing, only the fetch eventlistener to check what http request are being made and then filter the off-domain ones.

Comment: are you already using a CSP directive on the page? If not, that's a good way to cut down on lots of those obscure corner cases...

Comment: I'm not yet using a CSP directive. You actually gave me the right search term for something I thought might already exist - a way to block cross-origin requests that would supercede CORS allowances. I'm pretty happy about that.